# Prevent elements to be automatically in :focus state

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

If I open the ngx-bootstrap's modal, some elements are automatically focused (got blue borders around). Sometimes it's the x button in the upper corner, sometimes it's a tab from tabset module. Can I somehow prevent this auto focusing? Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vteaq9).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it doesn't solve straight away the auto-focus thing, but you can try to use css to remove those lines: `outline: none`

Comment: It's good, because as I was thinking about that now, disabling focus is maybe not the best solution for accessibility. I only want to prevent that outline from displaying.